camera doesnt work on android 13+ in flutter
this is my permissions :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>


  <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

and im using images_picker: ^1.2.11 , and permission_handler: ^11.0.1
and all the accesses are granted in the app in my phone ( camera , photos , audio , ... )
and i can pick images from gallery , but the camera doesnt work , the error message I got is this :
Read memory card access denied
with this code :
     PermissionStatus status = await Permission.camera.request();

if i print the statuse it says granted , but still camera doesnt work , my andoidn is above 13 , and please remeber the file picking from gallery is working , only camera doesnt work , any idea? thanks

based on documentation, FilePicker doest provide to open camera. use image_picker instead. https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

sorry my mistake to mention i use  images_picker: ^1.2.11 , i will edit my question
